# How to pass in android a RPC Json with nested parameters

Tags: android, json, json-rpc

What is the right code to pass a json with nested parameters in this form

```
 {"method":"startSession",
"params": [ "email": "testmail@test.it", 
            "password": "1234", 
            "stayLogged": "1", 
            "idClient": "ANDROID"
           ]
}
```

to a webservice URL that receive RPC??

the webservice code is

```
 @Webservice(paramNames = {"email", "password", "stayLogged", "idClient"},
public Response startSession(String email, String password, Boolean stayLogged, String idClient) throws Exception {
    boolean rC = stayLogged != null && stayLogged.booleanValue();
    UserService us = new UserService();
    User u = us.getUsersernamePassword(email, password);
    if (u == null || u.getActive() != null && !u.getActive().booleanValue()) {
        return ErrorResponse.getAccessDenied(id, logger);
    }
    InfoSession is = null;
    String newKey = null;
    while (newKey == null) {
        newKey = UserService.md5(Math.random() + " " + new Date().getTime());
        if (SessionManager.get(newKey) != null) {
            newKey = null;
        } else {
            is = new InfoSession(u, rC, newKey);
            if (idClient != null && idClient.toUpperCase().equals("ANDROID")) {
                is.setClient("ANDROID");
            }
            SessionManager.add(newKey, is);
        }
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "New session started: " + newKey + " - User: " + u.getEmail());
    return new Response(new InfoSessionJson(newKey, is), null, id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using json-rpc 1.0 as there is no version indicator in your request.

First your missing your "id", so add that to the request.

Now here are 3 different things you could try.

1) You need to use an object {} instead of array [] if you are going to set name and value pairs.
Like:

```
{"method":"startSession",
"params": { "email": "testmail@test.it", 
            "password": "1234", 
            "stayLogged": "1", 
            "idClient": "ANDROID"
           },
 "id":100
}
```

2) If your json deserializer is requiring the array syntax [] then you may have to wrap your object {} in [] like:

```
{"method":"startSession",
"params": [{ "email": "testmail@test.it", 
            "password": "1234", 
            "stayLogged": "1", 
            "idClient": "ANDROID"
           }],
  "id":101
}
```

3) Finally, you could also try using positional params just in an array like:

```
{"method":"startSession",
"params": [ "testmail@test.it", 
            "1234", 
            "1", 
            "ANDROID"
           ],
   "id":102
}
```

Hope that helps.